# Local Storage in Google Chrome Application tab is missing data

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason Google Chrome Local Storage sub-tab located within Developer Tools -> Application -> Storage tab doesn't display data. When I enter localStorage in console, then local storage data is printed out. Please advise what might be an issue with my Chrome settings.

Comment: I've the same situation, sometimes it doesn't show anything. I guess there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug that has been reported here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701413

As a work around (until the bug is fixed) you can close & reopen Developer Tools after a page refresh - Local Storage should be visible in the Application tab on initial open of dev tools.